# Compare Difference of Successive Rows Within The Same Table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need help in comparing data in sql query.

I need to compare within the plan_group_id, what measure_id details having different min_target and max_target compared to the other plan_id

Example:

I mean, I needed to compare what plan measure under the same plan_grp_id have different values in min and max.

what if the values are:

[image]

another example:

[image]

Comment: Looking at this images I think you want simple subquery: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=630e8c289e49f14754aaba98efcb334a), but why isn't last row selected? It has the same measure_id (111) and plan_grp_id (3110) as fourth row and different min/max values.

Comment: you're right last row should be included. What simple subquery?

Comment: Please look at [this dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=630e8c289e49f14754aaba98efcb334a) which I provided previously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group by all three columns

```
select m.plan_id, m.plan_grp_id, m.measure_id
from plan_measure m
group by m.plan_id, m.plan_grp_id, m.measure_id
having min(m.min_target) <> max(m.min_target) or min(m.max_target) <> max(m.max_target);
```

Comment: sorry, my bad.
what I meant is I needed to compare what plan measure under the same Plan_grp_id have different values in min and max. I've updated my post again

Answer (score 0):

Looks like

```
SQL> with plan_measure (measure_id, min_target, max_target) as
  2    (select 111, 10, 10 from dual union all
  3     select 222, 20, 20 from dual union all
  4     select 333, 30, 30 from dual union all
  5     select 111, 33, 55 from dual union all
  6     select 222, 20, 20 from dual union all
  7     select 333, 30, 30 from dual union all
  8     select 111, 10, 10 from dual union all
  9     select 222, 20, 20 from dual union all
 10     select 111, 10, 10 from dual
 11    )
 12  select measure_id
 13  from plan_measure
 14  group by measure_id
 15  having min(min_target) <> max(max_target);

MEASURE_ID
----------
       111

SQL>
```

---

I have no idea what is `plan` table supposed to do here, though. It isn't related to `plan_measure` in any obvious way (not to me, at least).

Comment: I think my sample is incorrect. I've updated my uploaded pic

Comment: plan table has the plan_grp_id and plan_id
plan measure table has plan_id and measure_id
measure table has the measure_id, min and max

Comment: You are talking about 2 tables, while your image shows only one and that makes confusion.

Comment: No, I needed to compare what plan measure under the same Plan_grp_id have different values in min and max. I've updated my post again